# Lite C language - Rebalancing strategy

Tags: algorithmic-trading, rebalancing

Intro: The strategy is to do an ordinary monthly rebalancing to predetermined weights, but modified to have a volatility target for each stock position (i.e. reduce/increase the positions that have recently been more/less volatile than their target vol), implemented with the Lite C language.

Script:

```
function run()
{
if(is(INITRUN)) 
  set(LOGFILE);
setf(SaveMode,SV_STATS);

//Basic setting
StartDate= 20000101;
EndDate = 20231001;
setf(PlotMode, PL_FINE);
BarPeriod = 1440;
Capital = 5000;

var Weights[3],Strengths[3],target_vol[3],vol[3];
var pool = Capital + ProfitClosed;
string Stock,Stocks[3];
assetList("AssetsFix");
while(Stock = loop("VTI","GLD","TLT"))
  {
    if(Init) assetHistory(Stock,FROM_YAHOO);
    asset(Stock);
    Stocks[Itor1] = Stock;
         vol[Itor1]=Volatility(series(priceClose(0)),60);
  }
  if(month(0) != month(1)) // at any month
  {
    int i;
    for(i = 0; i<3; i++) {
      asset(Stocks[i]);
                Weights[i] = 0.333;
                target_vol[i] = 0.15;
      int NewShares = (target_vol[i]/vol[i])*Weights[i]*pool/priceClose(0) - LotsPool;
      if(NewShares > 0)
        enterLong(NewShares);
      else if(NewShares < 0)
        exitLong("",-NewShares);
    }
  } 

}
```

The Challenge: However the execution is not as expected, only VTI is entered in the first month

[image]

Comment: Where is LotsPool given a value ?! (More generally you need to set a bunch of values before you do the i=0 iteration).